# Multiple database on login Django

Tags: django

i have an App that using a DB(default) now the problem is the client need multiple Factory.

One DB for one Factory, The idea is when the client login select the Factory write the user and password and redirect to the data of the factory selected.

[image]

The problem is how switch the respective DB as principal when the user login.

i read the Documentation but dont talk about this topic, please any suggest i don't know by where start..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating I found a very interesting concept ***Multi-Tenant***

The apps with **Multi-Tenant** allow serving multiple clients with the same app.

Each client has their data completely isolated in such architecture.

Tenants are identified via their host name (i.e tenant.domain.com). This information is stored on a table on the public schema.

Whenever a request is made, the host name is used to match a tenant in the database. If there's a match, the search path is updated to use this tenant's schema. So from now on all queries will take place at the tenant's schema.

[django-db-multitenant](https://github.com/mik3y/django-db-multitenant)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom model that keeps track of your databases, and assigns users to them based on a rule you created. You can then use the `.using()` QuerySet method to pull information based on the user's associated database.

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset